# MS Excel: How to Find & Replace 15+ character text preventing becoming Scientific Notation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

### Problem Statement

We have an Excel Sheet with a column of data like below:

```
+-----------------------+
| XYZ Data              |
+-----------------------+
| XYZ:12345678912345678 |
| XYZ:98765432198765432 |
| XYZ:12345678912345    |
+-----------------------+
```

We deliberately prepended the `XYZ:` before the original data to prevent becoming Scientific Notation in MS Excel.

Now we need to find `XYZ:` and replace it with an empty string so that we can get our original value.

### What already Tried

What we've already tried:

1. Find `XYZ:` & Replace with `` - ❌we failed
2. Find `XYZ:` & Replace with `` with Formatting `Text` - ❌we failed
3. Find `XYZ:` & Replace with `` with Formatting `Custom` with `#################` - ❌we failed

In all the cases the replaced data immediately becomes Scientifically notated

**Is there a way we can get our original value back in MS Excel?**

### A Glimpse of Light

However,
We could solve the issue with a formula like this:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("XYZ:", A1)), MID(A1, 5, LEN(A1)-4), A1)`

### But...

However, the process is lengthy and needs special training which is impossible for mass/external audiences.

Any smarter solution other than this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have tried using `TEXTAFTER()` & `REPLACE()` and retain the data type as text, as in `Excel` automatically converts numbers that are longer than 11 digits into scientific notations. `=TEXTAFTER(A2:A4,":")` or `=REPLACE(A2:A4,1,4,)`, note that the data type should be retained as text and not formatted to a number by adding a 0 or double unary etc.

Comment: `=REPLACE(A2:A4,1,4,)` is a good solution and worked for me. You can add that as an answer. But after replacing strings and placing them into a new column, if we remove the original column - data from the new column also gets removed. How can we retain the new column, but delete the original column after conversion? If your answer could shed some light on this context, it would be a plus. BTW, thanks for the easier solution.

Comment: For that you need to copy and value paste the same as formula column, or you can use Power Query here, let me post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above and as mentioned above by OP, posting the same as an answer.

---

**Using Excel Formulas**

• Using `TEXTAFTER()` --> Works with `MS365`

```
=TEXTAFTER(A2:A4,":")
```

---

• Using `REPLACE()` --> Works with `All Versions`

```
=REPLACE(A2:A4,1,4,)
```

---

[image]

---

Now, to remove the original column so as to retain the formulated cells as values then we can do the following by using `Power Query` or Copy the formulated cells and paste as values.

[image]

---

• Using `POWER QUERY`

[image]

---

For `POWER QUERY` instead of a explanation i have posted a `.gif` so as one can follow and resolve the same.

---

Another way in `POWER QUERY` to use `REPLACE` feature

[image]

---

**Addendum**(*Because those who are new this may not be aware*)**:** In the above `POWER QUERY` approaches one may find that the data types are not getting changed automatically i.e. not creating the changed type step because, by default i have disabled the feature from `QUERY OPTIONS`.

**How to disable that?**

• `File` --> `Options & Settings` --> `Query Options` --> From `Global Group` --> Select `Data Load` and **uncheck** under `Type Detection` the second option and **check** only `Never detect columns types...` --> OK. see screenshot for your reference

[image]

---

So another alternative, which I completely forgot since the required method was using formulas, thanks to **[MGonet](https://superuser.com/users/1832622/mgonet)** , using `Text To Columns`. Yes also with the **[Control data conversions](https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/control-data-conversions-in-excel)** this can also be prevented. **[MSFT Documentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-automatic-data-conversions-33d1d872-9926-4ef3-9364-492444d0c7ea)**

Follow the steps:

[image]

---

Comment: In Excel 365 there are new options to prevent conversion of long numers to scientific format or truncation after 15th digit. https://www.excelcampus.com/tips/automatic-data-conversion/ Now they are generally available. You should set the text format before you enter long number or precede it with an apostrophe.  In older versions of Excel you can also use `Text to Columns` feature using text format for the number to be extracted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate answer. And those GIFs will help anybody in the future. Thank you, Mayukh.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam glad to know that it has worked. Cheers !!